# Значение слова "скучень"

Tags: этимология, лексика

У Тынянова в "Восковой персоне" попадается это слово: "...но тут не было женщин, а был олень и другие скучни". Дело происходит в Портретной палате, и контекст подсказывает, помимо обычного значения "скучный предмет", толкование "чучело". Есть ли какие-то корни для таких предположений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, здесь-то как раз в том самом значении "скучный". Дело-то в было в Кунсткамере. Ягужинский пошёл жаловаться на Меньшикова и других покойному Петру 1,приблизившись к восковой фигуре Петра, подумал, что Пётр не в настроении, его могут развеселить только женщины, а здесь скучень - одни восковые фигуры, чучела, заспиртованные останки (в Кунсткамере была комната Петра), значит, он его выгонит, что и произошло: восковая фигура Петра показала рукой "Вон!".

А в другом значении слово есть - от "куча, кучно": колокольчик скученный, скучень - цветки в куче на стебле.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, двойственность здесь натянута. Подумалось, что "куча" и "чучело" в каком-то смысле не очень далеки. Но это не для Тынянова, вот Бродский любил так пошалить.